# There are at most ceiling(n/2^(h+1)) nodes of height h in any n-element tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

The reference is from Intro to Algorithms, pg 157. The image has 10 nodes and the height of the tree is 3.

My question is how does this hold when h=1?

ceiling(n/2^(h+1))= ceiling(10/2^(1+1))=ceiling(10/4)=ceiling(2.5)=3 nodes. However h=1 has 4 nodes.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The height of a node is the number of edges on the longest downward path between the node and a leaf.

With a binary tree of height 1, there can only be the root node, the left leaf, and the right leaf. That is a grand total of 3.

in the image, only 2, 16 and 3 are nodes of height 1.

Comment: Oh i understand now, i thought essentially it was saying that we could find the number of nodes of a tree at any height, not OF the height of the tree. Basically i thought it was saying the same thing as 2^i where i is the level of the tree. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

What about h = 2, we only have single node at h = 2 i.e 1 but according to formula **ceil(N/2^(h+1))** we have 2 nodes thats absolutely false.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34625839)